# How to convert Dic Post to Serialized Object in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, serialization

How to convert Dic Post to Serialized Object?

I do not know if the output is correct. Someone could help with this doubt. Thank you very much.

Post html form

```
{
'pergunta[4][item][11][quarto][0]': 'AA', 
'pergunta[4][item][11][quarto][1]': 'AA', 
'pergunta[4][item][11][segundo][0]': '123'
}
```

As should

```
{
  'pergunta':[
      'item': [
          {'quarto':[
            0: 'AA',
            1: 'AA'
          ]},
          { 'segundo': [
           0: '123'
          ]}
       ]
  ]
}
```

Edit

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Total" type="number" name="pergunta[{{ pergunta.id }}][item][{{ opcao.id }}][]">
```

Comment: can you show your form?

Comment: Hi, Mauricio. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get a JSON file the way you expect it because you can't iterate the inputs trough the name. The name is just an identifier and it is passed as a string.

The solution would be 1) change your form so you can get the JSON file as you expect or 2) create a function that allow to you to work with this string